# What is the logging request in computer programming?

Tags: design-patterns, logging

I'm learning `Command Pattern`, one of the uses of this pattern is to implement logging requests. I read a little about logging request in Head First Design Pattern book, but I didn't understand what does it?

Command Pattern definition:

> Encapsulate a request as an object, thereby letting you parameterize clients with different requests, queue or **log requests**, and support undoable operations.

Comment: Please post the example code, I don't think that everyone has the book  on hand.

Comment: I havn't any example code, but this book say it is for transactional operations.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is talking about something called a logging request at all. It's just saying that if you represent requests as objects then it makes it easy to add them to a queue or to write information about them out to a log.

Comment: That is my interpretation too.